# Preserving read push notifications

Tags: ios, ipad, push-notification

I was wondering if it's possible to keep the last 5 (for example) read notifications in the apple's notification center (the one that shows up when you swipe down near the top)

I've noticed that once you click on a notification and "read" it, it disappears from the list. Is this done programaticaly by the app, who sends the device a message that the notification has been read and it's ok to delete it, or is it done automatically by the device and you have absolutely no control on it.

One client said it saw an app that did this and kept the last 5 notifications there, regardless if they were accessed or not but so far I've found nothing to indicate that this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a very complete answer, but one of my colleagues managed to make this work.
All he did was to stop using badge number for notifications. No badge number is set when a notification is received, and no badge number is set when a notification is read.

[edit]It seems that when you set the badge number to 0 after you receive the notification, iOS automatically clears the notification, this being an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can only "read" the notifications sent to your App, and only if the user explicitly used their "action" button to open your App. if that was the scenario you can use:

```
// Handle local notification if received
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"received a local notification = %@", [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]);
    // Do something, save it..
}

// Handle remote notification if received
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil) {
    NSlog(@"received a remote notification = %@", [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]);
    // Do something, save it..
}
```

Or other alternatives (NotificationCenter etc) to read the notification when the app is opened with it and save it persistently.

Comment: We already have the reading part working, there was no problem here. The PUSH works on our apps, it's just that the notifications disappear after being read, which is not the case with other apps, who still keep the last X notifications in the Notification Center, regardless if they were read or not